# class does not have a method 'urldecode'

Tags: php

In PHP how can I use the urldecode() inside a class. I have the following class

```
class exam
{
  function __constract()
  {
    $this->get = $_GET;
    //decode the url
    array_walk_recursive($this->get, array($this, 'urldecode'));
  }
}
```

because it showing the error

> Warning: array_walk_recursive() expects parameter 2 to be a valid
>   callback, class 'exam' does not have a method 'urldecode' on line 7

Comment: You need to show us the `Pariksha` class.

Comment: Well.. it is clearly telling you that :class 'exam' does not have a method 'urldecode' ... but you are trying to call this method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing the current object `$this` and the method name `urldecode` so it's looking for `$this->urldecode()`.  Just pass in the name of the built-in function:

```
array_walk_recursive($this->get, 'urldecode');
```

However `$_GET` variables are already decoded. From [urldecode()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php):

> **Warning**
>   The superglobals `$_GET` and `$_REQUEST` are already decoded. Using `urldecode()` on an element in `$_GET` or `$_REQUEST` could have unexpected and dangerous results.

Comment: Thank you very much sir, for your valuable answer.